# SVG fill on text change on hover

Tags: html, css, svg

I am attempting to animate an SVG on hover, I want the text to change on hover, I am trying this with **pure css**. Basically you hover on the circle path, and the text path has a css class called that changes its fill.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ucm69vbe/)

HTML:

```
<div class="holder">
  <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 170.36 170.36">
    <defs>
    <style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;}.cls-2,.cls-3,.cls-4{fill:#9b00f4;}.cls-3{font-size:56.54px;}.cls-3,.cls-4{font-family:Raleway-Bold, Raleway;font-weight:700;}.cls-4{font-size:48.97px;}</style>
    </defs>
    <circle class="circle-1" cx="960.15" cy="540.18" r="83.18" transform="translate(-1008.6 -46.45) rotate(-22.5)"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M960.15,459A81.18,81.18,0,1,1,879,540.18,81.28,81.28,0,0,1,960.15,459m0-4a85.18,85.18,0,1,0,85.18,85.18A85.18,85.18,0,0,0,960.15,455Z" transform="translate(-874.97 -455)"/>
    <text class="cls-3 main-text" transform="translate(73.19 99.05)">1</text>
    <text class="cls-4 alt-text" transform="translate(70.67 94.69) rotate(0.08)">2</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.holder{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.circle-1{
  fill:white;
}
.circle-1:hover{
  fill:purple;
}
.main-text{
  display: block;
}
.alt-text{
  display:none;
}
/* Doesn't work */
.circle-1:hover .main-text{
  display:none;
}
.circle-1:hover .alt-text{
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.circle-1` is a not a parent for the text elements but a **sibling**, so you need to use the [sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

```css
.holder{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.circle-1{
  fill:white;
}
.circle-1:hover{
  fill:purple;
}
.main-text{
  display: block;
}
.alt-text{
  display:none;
}
.circle-1:hover ~ .main-text{
  display:none;
}
.circle-1:hover ~ .alt-text{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 170.36 170.36">
    <defs>
    <style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;}.cls-2,.cls-3,.cls-4{fill:#9b00f4;}.cls-3{font-size:56.54px;}.cls-3,.cls-4{font-family:Raleway-Bold, Raleway;font-weight:700;}.cls-4{font-size:48.97px;}</style>
    </defs>
    <circle class="circle-1" cx="960.15" cy="540.18" r="83.18" transform="translate(-1008.6 -46.45) rotate(-22.5)"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M960.15,459A81.18,81.18,0,1,1,879,540.18,81.28,81.28,0,0,1,960.15,459m0-4a85.18,85.18,0,1,0,85.18,85.18A85.18,85.18,0,0,0,960.15,455Z" transform="translate(-874.97 -455)"/>
    <text class="cls-3 main-text" transform="translate(73.19 99.05)">1</text>
    <text class="cls-4 alt-text" transform="translate(70.67 94.69) rotate(0.08)">2</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```